# Show Tables belonging to User category

Tags: php, datatables, laravel-8

My question is simple, currently I have my system showing a Table and all its entries:

```
    <table id="inventarios" class="table table-striped table-bordered shadow-lg mt-4" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">Unidad</th>
            <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($inventarios->where('uni_id',) as $inventario )
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventario->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventario->nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventario->uni_id}}</td>
                <td>
                    <form action="{{ route ('inventarios.destroy',$inventario->id) }}" method="POST">
                        <a href="/inventarios/{{$inventario->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a>
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
                    </form>

                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

The problem is that Only the user tagged as ADMIN should view ALL the entries, and the rest of the user should view only the tables that belong to their unit.

Each created user belongs to a Unit, and this unit can create "Inventarios". I want to know how to let the user see their own "Inventarios" and not all the entries on the table.

I'm working in Laravel 8, PHP.

Comment: Post a sample of your table...

Answer (score 0):

Once you define user roles (Admin, Unit User, etc) you can deploy something like laravel-permission that save a lot of code and can give you some hand on this. Other is check for logged user like Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')

```
public function index()
{
   $inventarios = '';
   if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin'))
     $inventarios = Inventario::all();
   else
     $inventario = Inventario::where('uni_id',Auth::user()->uni_id)->get();
   return view( .... , compact('inventarios'));
}
```

I this something like this could work